# Strip all non-numeric characters from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Consider a non-DOM scenario where you'd want to remove all non-numeric characters from a string using JavaScript/ECMAScript. Any characters that are in range `0 - 9` should be kept.

```
var myString = 'abc123.8<blah>';

//desired output is 1238
```

How would you achieve this in plain JavaScript? Please remember this is a non-DOM scenario, so jQuery and other solutions involving browser and keypress events aren't suitable.

Answer (score 1976, accepted):

Use the string's [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a regex of `\D`, which is a shorthand character class that matches all non-digits:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Comment: Thanks csj; anyplace to find more info on `\D` ?

Comment: This is my default regex reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

The built-in character classes each have built-in complements.
\d \D (digits versus everything but digits)
\w \W (word charcters versus everything but word characters)
\s \S (whitespace versus everything but whitespace)

Comment: Just to be clear, here is the syntax for replace: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp because the forward slashes and the "g" are part of that command, not part of the RegEx.

Comment: does `replace` work with this exact syntax in all browsers? seems like I remember getting an `object has no method 'replace' ` in an older version of IE when using this with text I grabbed with jQuery... or something like that.

Comment: @cwd I have no idea what has been supported in past or current browsers. The question specified a non-DOM context, so it's likely that the poster was scripting in a non web browser environment.

Comment: Great tool to test regular expression online (It's not mine :)). 
https://regex101.com

Comment: i tried following but nothing worked

"this.value = this.value.replace(eval(!/^[A-Za-z\d.#-,]$/),'')"  

"this.value = this.value.replace(eval(/^[A-Za-z\d.#-,]$/),'')"   

"this.value = this.value.replace(eval(specialCharRegex),'')"    

what should i do?

Comment: You can use `String(myString).replace(/\D/g,'')` in case they pass only a number this code won't throw an error.

Comment: this works fine for positive integers but goodbye negative numbers.

Comment: This turns `1.2` into `12`

Comment: @skilleo fair enough, but the OP did eventually edit their question to indicate that they were seeking to preserve the digits themselves. 0-9

Comment: @adamdport The OP's example specifically shows a period being stripped away.

Answer (score 478):

If you need this to leave the dot for float numbers, use this

```
var s = "-12345.50 €".replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''); // gives "-12345.50"
```

Comment: Any regexp experts? How to make this allow only a single dot (very relevant with numbers). Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean? give input and output example

Comment: I mean, it currently accepts for example "1..56" and "1.5.28", right? Is it possible to make it accept only numbers with a single dot, such as "1.56"?

Comment: use http://stackoverflow.com/a/16951568/579646 to test it like this: new RegExp(/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/).test("1.5.28")

Comment: Is that possible to change all `,` by `.` in your regex? In some countries, the comma is used as a separator instead of the point. :)

Comment: @Mistalis it is, but be aware, in such cases there is possibilty they are both there (Eg. 1,000,000.5) - so you should rather do .replace(/",","."/g) first :)

Comment: @max4ever Whats with the "`-`" in the regexp?

Comment: Not good: `"aaa 2.9px of bbb.".replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')` → `2.9.` Should strip any String which might surround a Number..

Comment: Great test! my first idea is [^\d.-]+[^\d]+ should work in this case

Comment: @max4ever you saved my life, thanks for handling `-`(negative) number case :)

Comment: @Kasperi perhaps:
`parseFloat("-1234.5.50 €".replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''))`

Comment: Great answer, if you want a numeric field you mean any number event floats :)

Answer (score 81):

Use a regular expression, if your script implementation supports them. Something like:

```
myString.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Comment: For some reason this way seems much more readable than [^\d].

Comment: whats the g for after the regex delimiter??

Comment: @NativeCoder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993629/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-g-flag-in-regular-expressions

Comment: will not work for float/decimal values for example, "7.6$" will return 76

Comment: like @SikandarTariq mentioned but also negative values.

Answer (score 39):

You can use a RegExp to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) all the non-digit characters:

```
var myString = 'abc123.8<blah>';
myString = myString.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); // 1238
```

Answer (score 35):

Something along the lines of:

```
yourString = yourString.replace ( /[^0-9]/g, '' );
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the original question, but a version to handle the decimal point: `yourString = yourString.replace ( /[^0-9.]/g, '' );`

Comment: Late to the party but also need dash and comma. In certain regions decimal is done with a comma: `replace(/[^0-9.,-]/g, ''`

Answer (score 33):

Short function to remove all non-numeric characters but keep the decimal (and return the number):

```js
parseNum = str => +str.replace(/[^.\d]/g, '');
let str = 'a1b2c.d3e';
console.log(parseNum(str));
```

Comment: For me, this is better than the accepted answer, because it keeps the decimal.

Comment: You might want to add "-" as well because the number can be negative as well.

Comment: ...but only if `-` is the first character

Comment: this does WRONG for the input `my text: 9123.11, okay.?`

Answer (score 7):

The problem with these answers above, is that it assumes whole numbers.  But if you need a floating point value, then the previous reg string will remove the decimal point.

To correct this you need write a negated character class with ^

```
var mystring = mystring.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
```

Comment: this does WRONG for the input `my text: 9123.11 okay.`

Answer (score 4):

In Angular / Ionic / VueJS -- I just came up with a simple method of:

```
stripNaN(txt: any) {
    return txt.toString().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
}
```

Usage on the view:

```
<a [href]="'tel:'+stripNaN(single.meta['phone'])" [innerHTML]="stripNaN(single.meta['phone'])"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately none of the answers above worked for me.

I was looking to convert currency numbers from strings like `$123,232,122.11` (1232332122.11) or `USD 123,122.892` (123122.892) or any currency like `₹ 98,79,112.50` (9879112.5) to give me a number output including the decimal pointer.

Had to make my own regex which looks something like this:

```
str = str.match(/\d|\./g).join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
myString.match(/\d/g).join``
```

```js
var myString = 'abc123.8<blah>'
console.log( myString.match(/\d/g).join`` );
```

Comment: how does this work?

Comment: @1252748 match will filter all digits and put them into array, join will glue array elements into single string

Comment: i meant the join with the backticks. what's going on there?

Comment: @1252748 read about: `js tagged templates`

Comment: Yeah I've seen tagged templates, just don't understand what is going on with join using them. Is this just saving two characters, invoking join with a single argument `""`?

Answer (score 1):

This,

```
.match(/\d|\.|\-/g).join('');
```

Handles both `,` and `.` also `-`

Example:

`"Balance -$100,00.50".match(/\d|\.|\-/g).join('');`

Outputs

`-10000.50`

Answer (score -5):

we are in **2017** now you can also use **ES2016**

```
var a = 'abc123.8<blah>';
console.log([...a].filter( e => isFinite(e)).join(''));
```

or

```
console.log([...'abc123.8<blah>'].filter( e => isFinite(e)).join(''));
```

The result is

```
1238
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to go about this operation.

Comment: It converts the string into an array of single-character strings via a spare method, and then applies filter function over JavaScript on each array item, returning a new string array, to finally join that array back into a string. Regex takes a string and returns a string and the processing is done via native code.