# Remove all non-digit characters from a string jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: strip out non-numeric characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/javascript-strip-out-non-numeric-characters-from-string)

String matching is headache for me.

**Example:**

If I have strings like these:

```
abc123xyz456()*
^%$111u222
```

Then convert it to:

```
123456
111222
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/javascript-strip-out-non-numeric-characters-from-string

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about regular expressions?

Try something something like:

```
'abc123xyz456()*'.replace(/\D/g,'')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input id='num' value='hgjhGJHGt7y67ihgGUT&6tb.,.,z.oy8'/>


$('#num').val($('#num').val().replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
```