# How to remove the character using index in my case using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, char

I am trying to remove the character from where the alphabets are occurs.

**For example**

```
var str1 = 1001;
// if there is no alphabates, then i want to print same as it is,
//so, output: 1001

var str2 = 1001R
var str3 = 1001R1

//Expecting output = 1001 for both str2 and str3
```

I tried this way

```
var selecteVendorID = $(".chequeTable .selected .tdVendorID").text(); //1001
alert('before : ' + selecteVendorID);  //before : 1001

selecteVendorID = selecteVendorID.slice(0, selecteVendorID.indexOf(selecteVendorID.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)));
alert(selecteVendorID);  //100
```

it is removing last number.

**Note**

> if `var str = '1001R'`
>
> that above code is working properly,

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388055/remove-all-non-digit-characters-from-a-string-jquery

Answer (score 0):

javascript slice() method with negative arguments search from the backward direction.

In your case, when the regex doesn't match, it returns a -1, which evaluates to the function being `string.slice(0, -1)` which means, from the beginning to 1 from the last.

Change the code to :

```
firstAlphaIndex = selecteVendorID.indexOf(selecteVendorID.match(/[a-zA-Z]/));
selecteVendorID = selecteVendorID.slice(0, firstAlphaIndex>0?firstAlphaIndex:selecteVendorID.length);
alert(selecteVendorID);  //100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
Var str = '100f1';
var position= str.indexOf(str.match(/[a-z A-Z]));
Var res= str.substring(0,position)+ str.substring(position+1, strict.length);
```