# Count the number of integers in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I count the number of integers in a string using jQuery or javascript?

For example g66ghy7  = 3

Comment: Is this a homework? If so, please add the [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag.

Comment: Isn't 66 an integer? I think you meant "digits" :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
alert("g66ghy7".replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length);
```

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFmEB/).

Comment: Heh, just not to mess it with this: `/^[0-9]/g` :)  http://jsfiddle.net/a52bokjf/1/

Answer (score 9):

I find this to look pretty/simple:

```
var count = ('1a2b3c'.match(/\d/g) || []).length
```

A RegExp will probably perform better ([it appears](http://jsperf.com/count-integers-in-string)):

```
var r = new RegExp('\\d', 'g')
  , count = 0

while(r.exec('1a2b3c')) count++;
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution would be to use a regular expression to replace all *but* the numeric values and pull out the length afterwards. Consider the following:

```
var s = 'g66ghy7'; 
alert(s.replace(/\D/g, '').length); //3
```

Comment: Should not be s.replace('/\d/g') enough?

Comment: `\D` means non-numeric, so `s.replace(/\D/g, '')`

Comment: I like this one, simple and effective. Found it also here, just missing the count part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-string

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet:

```
str.match(/\d/g)?.length || 0
```

Thanks to @CertainPerformance answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67247072/1205871)

```js
const str = 'g66ghy7'
const digitCount = str.match(/\d/g)?.length || 0;
console.log('digitCount', digitCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little longer alternative is to convert each char to a number; if it doesn't fail, raise the counter.

```
var sTest = "g66ghy7";

var iCount = 0;
for (iIndex in sTest) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(sTest[iIndex]))) {
        iCount++;
    }
}
alert(iCount);
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYDZD/1/).

Answer (score 0):

A simple for can solve this:

```js
const value = "test:23:string236";

let totalNumbers = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        const element = value[i];        
        if (isFinite(element)) {
            totalNumbers++;
        }
    }
    
console.log(totalNumbers);
```