# Textbox has to only accept 10 numbers. No more no less in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox

How do you make a textbox only accept 10 numbers and it could also accept () -

example: 123-123-1234
or 
example: 1231231234
or 
example: (123)123-1234

if the text box does not contain any of these example it should give a error message.

Comment: Is this web or Winforms or WPF?

Comment: @rikkigibson Windows Form

Answer (score 1):

The MaskedTextBox in Windows Forms is designed to restrict input to conform to a pattern and gracefully let the user know if they're entering data that's against that pattern.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kkx4h3az(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The masked textbox is a good tool but i dont know how to make the mask text box give me an error if the user doesn't have 10 numbers in it.

Comment: You need to handle the validation failed event as demonstrated in the article.

Comment: This article is great for the DateTime, but it does not explain how to validate a phone number

Comment: Look in the ... menu by Mask in the Properties window of the designer. If that doesn't have a premade mask for phone numbers, you can invent one by experimenting with the example pattern used for dates in the tutorial-- just, instead of "00/00/0000" try "000-000-0000" or something.

Comment: I can got the masked textbox in my form. I can input numbers in it like "000-000-0000" but the thing is when i click a button, and if a user missed a number in the masked textbox. User types this: "000-000-000_"<--They forgot a number. How do you program the masked textbox to show you can error, by the click of the button.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me out, but i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this with server-code, but it is nice to have a client-side validator as well.

Server-side: As Rikkigibson already pointed out, [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kkx4h3az%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is a good control to achieve this. Example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ToolTip1.IsBalloon = True
    Me.MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000"
End Sub

Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(sender as Object, e as MaskInputRejectedEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.MaskInputRejected
    ToolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Invalid Input"
    ToolTip1.Show("We're sorry, but only digits (0-9) are allowed in dates.", MaskedTextBox1, 5000)
End Sub
```

Read here about the [Mask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `property`.

Client-side: It is good to have a client-side validation as well, so, no request with wrong value in the textbox would reach and burden your server. To do this in jQuery, you can handle the [.keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event of your textbox. So, if you have a validation function, and we assume that selector corresponds to your textbox, then you should write a code, like

```
$(selector).keyup(function(e) {
    if (validation(e)) {
        //it is valid
    } else {
        //it is not valid
    }
});
```

EDIT:

I have seen you have a problem with the number of digits as well. [This](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/669502-count-occurances-digits-string) is how you get the number of digits in a `String` using vb and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657824/count-the-number-of-integers-in-a-string) is how you get it in Javascript.

Comment: If i approached this issue with the masked textbox for the phone number the user can miss a number example: (123) 123-123_ and still be able to bypass the program with no warnings. is there a way to prompt the user an error message with the masked textbox indicating that they dont have enough numbers in the maskedtextbox @Lajos Arpad

Comment: The comment on the original post mentions that this Winforms, not web, so there's no VB vs JavaScript concern here.

Comment: @rikkigibson, you are right, we can forget about the Javascript part.

Comment: @LajosArpad , yes I'm using the phone number mask. This is for validating phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me out, but i figured it out