# Regex - String should not include more than 7 digits

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Rules for String:

- Can contain 0-7 digits

---

Test Cases :

- `abcd1234ghi567` ⟶ `True`
- `1234567abc` ⟶ `true`
- `ab1234cd567` ⟶ `true`
- `abc12` ⟶ `True`
- `abc12345678` ⟶ `False`

How do I come up with a regular expression for the same?

The problem I am facing is - How to keep the count of digits in the whole string. The digits can occur any where in the string.

I would like a **Pure regex solution**

Comment: Check `"abc12345678".match(/\d/g).length` in an if statement.

Comment: I wanted a regex without having to use it in a function

Comment: @supritashankar: for what reason?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I wanted as a part of my json schema. Did not want to include my function.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for: [Count the number of integers in a string \[regexp\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657824/count-the-number-of-integers-in-a-string)

Comment: If you want a pure regex solution that doesn't include any JavaScript code, you should explicitly mention it and not include the `JavaScript` tag in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured it out!

`/^(\D*\d?\D*){0,7}$/`

Every numeric char can be surrounded by non-numeric chars.

Answer (score 6):

## Approach 1

If you're OK with putting some of your logic in your JavaScript, something as simple as this function should do :

```
function validate(teststring) {
    return teststring.match(/\d/g).length < 8;
}
```

#### Demo

```js
function validate(teststring) {
    return teststring.match(/\d/g).length < 8;
}

document.body.innerHTML =
    '<b>abcd1234ghi567 :</b> ' + validate('abcd1234ghi567') + '<br />' +
    '<b>1234567abc :</b> ' + validate('1234567abc') + '<br />'+
    '<b>ab1234cd567 :</b> ' + validate('ab1234cd567') + '<br />'+
    '<b>abc12 :</b> ' + validate('abc12') + '<br />'+
    '<b>abc12345678 :</b> ' + validate('abc12345678') + '<br />';
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bbphs0km/1/))

---

## Approach 2

If you prefer all of your logic to be in your regex instead of your JavaScript, you could use a regex like `/^(\D*\d?\D*){7}$/` or `/^([^0-9]*[0-9]?[^0-9]*){7}$/` and use [**RegExp.prototype.test()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of [**String.prototype.match()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to test your strings.

In that case, your validate function would look something like this :

```
function validate(teststring) {
    return /^([^0-9]*[0-9]?[^0-9]*){7}$/.test(teststring);
}
```

#### Demo :

```js
function validate(teststring) {
    return /^([^0-9]*[0-9]?[^0-9]*){7}$/.test(teststring);
}

document.body.innerHTML =
    '<b>abcd1234ghi567 :</b> ' + validate('abcd1234ghi567') + '<br />' +
    '<b>1234567abc :</b> ' + validate('1234567abc') + '<br />'+
    '<b>ab1234cd567 :</b> ' + validate('ab1234cd567') + '<br />'+
    '<b>abc12 :</b> ' + validate('abc12') + '<br />'+
    '<b>abc12345678 :</b> ' + validate('abc12345678') + '<br />';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have added the answer below using regex only. Without having to using a function. Check it out.

Comment: Downvoting, because it doesn't fulfill the original requirement, which is a pure regex match.

Comment: @LennyMarkus : The question at no time explicitly mentioned that a pure regex solution was required, and it contain the tag `JavaScript`.

Comment: @LennyMarkus : Just for the sake of completeness, I added a second approach where the logic is put inside the regex only.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex can check if the total digits are less than 7:

```js
var i, strings = ["abcd1234ghi567", "1234567abc", "ab1234cd567", "abc12", "abc12345678"];
for (i of strings) {
  document.write(i + " -> " + /^(?:[\D]*[0-9][\D]*){0,7}$/.test(i) + "</br>");
}
```