# How do I get the amount of numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a text input in my HTML document and some buttons below it. When pressed, these will run a function **input(some number)**. I have added a feature to the function that prevents the length of the string for the input from being above 5. However, sometimes the string (**currentAnswer**) will be set to something like *-768.*. When this happens, the function will not let you enter any more numbers, when instead you should be able to enter 2 more digits. So how would I find the length of just the **numbers** in a string? Here is my code:

```
function input(num) {
currentAnswer = document.getElementById("answerBox").value;
answerLength = currentAnswer.length;

if (answerLength < 5) {

document.getElementById("answerBox").value = currentAnswer + num;
answerLength = answerLength + 1;

}}
```

As you can see, I am using **currentAnswer.length** to get the length of the string. But I only want the amount of digits. Can someone please help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657824/count-the-number-of-integers-in-a-string

Answer (score -2):

[Count the number of integers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657824/count-the-number-of-integers-in-a-string)

```
alert("g66ghy7".replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length);
```

:)

Comment: Don't duplicate a question & then just copy paste its answer please...