# How to count digits of date in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I should count how many digits are in date. For example I have date 13/13/2013 and I need to count these 8 digits. Does anyone know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of integers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657824/count-the-number-of-integers-in-a-string)

Comment: '13/13/2013'.length - 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const date = '13/13/2013';
console.log(date.match(/[0-9]/g).length)
```