# How to add validation for positive floating point number with 3 digits before decimal?

Tags: php, regex, yii

I have seen many links for floating point number validation but none of them for precision.

[only floating point number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)

I want the field to display error if the input is 1234.31 or . 
but not for 123.5555555 or .3433 or.9022. I need the rules to be specified to get 0 to 3 digit before decimal. I tried

```
/^[^+-][0-9]{0,3}[.]?[0-9]{0,2}/
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/^\d{0,3}\.\d+/
```

But if you want to use your regex, modify it like this:

```
/^[^+-][0-9]{0,3}[.]?[0-9]+/
```

Your original regex didn't work because you were making it to match only up to 2 decimal places. `+` in regex means 1 or many.

Comment: Thanks, but how to restrict if the input is just 256.?

Comment: are you coming to say `256.`?

Comment: Use my regex for that. That will do

Comment: Yes, use my regex for that. My regex will make sure that numbers before `.` are 0 to 3 digits and it has a `.` and followed by some digits.

Comment: No Joki, its not working. its through error when I tried 256.

Comment: array('weight','match', 'pattern'=>'/^\d{0,3}\.\d+/','message'=>'Add 0 to 3 digits before decimal'),

Comment: so is `256.` valid or not?

Comment: decimal should have atleast some characters after `.`

Comment: Thanks jogi, is that possible to make it accept numbers without decimal as well.256

Comment: Use this regex: `/^\d{0,3}\.?\d*/`

Comment: Thanks again Joki, last concern, I don't want it to accept plain "."?

Comment: @Abel, my name is Amit. Also it won't accept a plain `.`

Comment: Sorry Amit, I just used it as it is in the profile name.

Comment: Now I just add one more rule and its fine now. array('height,weight','numerical', 'integerOnly'=>false),

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much had it

```
/^([0-9]{0,3})?\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+$/
```

and use something like

```
if(!preg_match("^([0-9]{0,3})?\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+$/", $float)){}
```

Comment: Thanks, my concern is not much about the digits after decimal. Is that possible to make it accept digits without decimals as well, but not accepting a plain "."

Comment: @Abel Try my regex out and see for yourself but use a `!` 'not'. Or use this [test](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8dERfrSGUczd1ZBW) here by changing the `result` item.