# Max 3 digits, up to 3 decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

It seems I'm stuck again with a simple regex.

What I'd like:

- A number between 1 and 999
- Optional: a comma , sign
- If the comma sign is entered, minimum 1 decimal and maximum 3
  decimals should be presebt.

> Allowed:
>   100
>   999,0
>   999,999
>   999,99
>
> Disallowed:
>   -1
>   0
>   999,
>   999,9999

This is what I have so far:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\,[0-9]{1,3})?$
```

Any tips?

Comment: This is pretty much the same, it can be adapted trivially for your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901088/regex-numbers-between-xx-xxx-xx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\,\d{1,3})?$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rM9pF0/1)

Main difference from OP's regex is use of `[1-9]` which matches digits 1 to 9 before rest of the regex.

Comment: I'd love it if people actually explained what their regex does.

Comment: Hmm, weird. In your demo, it seems to work correctly. Still, when using this, it accepts a comma with no decimals and when decimals are present, the validation fails :s

Comment: I'm using Angular, using the ng-pattern directive: ng-pattern="/^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\,\d{1,3})?$/"

Comment: For some reason, even numbers like 9999,99999999 are accepted with this regex, while your demo clearly shows it shouild not. Very weird, but thanks for the help already!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79750/discussion-between-bv202-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 7):

This regex should work :

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{1,3})?$
```

Here is the explanation :

`^[1-9]`: It should begin with a number between 1 and 9

`\d{0,2}`: Followed by minimum 0, maximum 2 digits (0-9)

`(?:,`: Followed by a comma

`\d{1,3})?`: IF there is a comma it should be followed by one to three digits

`$`: End of line

[EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/hF9xU7/1)

Thanks @dev-null for this link: [Explanation](http://regexper.com/#%5E%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%3F%24)

Comment: I'd love it if people actually explained what their regex does.

Comment: @evolutionxbox http://regexper.com/#%5E%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%3F%24

Comment: [Same answer has already been posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30662081/548225)

Comment: Good explanation, thumbs up from me.