# Split values like "20px", "100%", "4.58 em", "-40px", ".40em", "-80", ".04" into value / unit pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working with CSS values in my js/jquery application and to make values like "20px" or "100%" or "4.58 em" editable, they need to be separated into value / unit pairs. My regex is patchy and so far I have come up with this after hours of tinkering.

```
split_unit : function (v) {
    if (typeof v === 'string' && v !== ""){
        var split = v.match(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)$/);
        return {'value':split[1].trim(),  'unit':split[2].trim()};
    }
    else{
        return { 'value':v, 'unit':"" }
    }
}
```

"split_unit" is a method that splits a values like "20px", "100%", "4.58 em", "440" or "9.4" to object containing value and unit.

It works nicely with values like **"20px", "100%", "4.58 em", "440" or "9.4"**,

however the regex does not appear to be working with negative values and values that start with a decimal point like so **"-40px", ".40em", "-80", ".04"** etc.

I can do a replace of the decimal point and the '-' minus/hyphen at the start of the function and then append it to the value string at the end, but there has to be a more elegant way of doing it.

How would I go about tweaking the regex or the function itself so it works with negative values and values starting with decimal points ?

Thank you for answering this and for your time.

Comment: `value = parseFloat(v); unit = v.split(value)[1];`

Comment: after the value, the unit is `[a-z]+` or `%` only

Comment: See [*Regular expression for floating point numbers*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers). Use `-?\d*\.?\d+` to match the float value.

Comment: @Teemu that looked brilliant .... until you try with `.40em` for example

Comment: `value = parseFloat(v); unit = v.match(/[a-z%]+/i)[0]`

Comment: Well, if you're missing `-` and `.` - just add them to your `\d`s. Like `[-.\d]` or something.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @Oleg V. Volkov, Jaromanda X, Teemu I've tried the suggestions and this seems to be working ( /^([-.\d]+(?:.\d+)?)(.*)$/ ), Thanks Oleg ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the comments @Oleg V. Volkov, @Jaromanda X @Teemu I've tried the suggestions and this seems to be working v.match(/^([-.\d]+(?:.\d+)?)(.*)$/);  Thanks Oleg ...

I'll run a few more tests and then confirm that this works 100%.

```
split_unit : function (v) {
    if (typeof v === 'string' && v !== ""){
        var split = v.match(/^([-.\d]+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)$/);
        return {'value':split[1].trim(),  'unit':split[2].trim()};
    }
    else{
        return { 'value':v, 'unit':"" }
    }
}
```

Works perfectly with the following strings:

"-.280em", "290px", "100%", "480", "4.80", "20px", "100%", "4.58 em", "-40px", ".40em", "-80", ".04"

Answer (score 0):

Use this complete code :

```
// Getting all unit+value from a string:

var m='40px 80px 45% .30px -25em'.match(/((-?)(\d)*(\.?))(\d)+(%|\w)*/gmi);

// Getting values :
var val1= m[0].match(/((-?)(\d)*(\.?))(\d)+/gmi)[0];

// Getting Unit :
var unit1=m[0].replace(/((-?)(\d)*(\.?))(\d)+/gmi,'')[0];
```

So based on your code you can use above code(let `v` be a match returning from my first line of code above) :

```
    split_unit : function (v) {
        if (typeof v === 'string' && v !== ""){

            return {'value':v.match(/((-?)(\d)*(\.?))(\d)+/gmi)[0], 
                    'unit':v.replace(/((-?)(\d)*(\.?))(\d)+/gmi,'')[0]};
        }
        else{
            return { 'value':v, 'unit':"" }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
var re = /(-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\D+)/;
var res = re.exec(".40 %");//  ==> [".40 %", ".40", "%"]
```

Revision, allow null for unit:

```
var re = /(-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\D*)/;
var res = re.exec(".40");//  ==> [".40 %", ".40", ""]
```

Comment: this appears to not work with "4.80", "-80", ".04", in which case the regex should match the whole value and return blank / null unit.

".40" becomes = [".", "", ".", index: 0, input: ".40"]
"4.80" becomes = ["4.", "4", ".", index: 0, input: "4.80"]