# Need a regex for float values

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number field in the form and am validating that number field for float values. But I need to restrict the float number to only one period (`.`)

For example:
`122.00`

But now its taking input like this also: `123.00.`.
I dont want allow another period (`.`) in the end again.

Is there any regex for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression for floating point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: [Why use regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37913037/477563)  JavaScript includes `parseFloat`.  If the return value is NaN then the input is not a valid float.

Answer (score 2):

Why use regular expressions?  JavaScript includes [`parseFloat`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) which returns `NaN` if the input was not a valid floating point:

```
var f = parseFloat(someString);
if ( isNaN(f) ) {
    // someString is not a valid float
}
```