# javascript regex optional minus

Tags: regex

I have the following function in javascript:

```
function unString(String){     
   var justNumbers = /(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?/;
   var result      = String.match(justNumbers);
   result *= 1;
   result = Math.round(result*100) / 100;
   return result;
}
```

The meaning of it is to extract the number out of every possible css value, so that it can be added or substracted or multiplied with other values:
e. g.

```
var newPadding = unString(  $('#myID').css("padding-bottom")  )*10 + "px";
```

Having modified my code I would now need the regex to allow an optional minus, to allow values like "-3px" be transformed to "-3" (actually the function can't and returns "0").

[I know there are tons of optional minus regex threads on stackoverflow and other forums, but they don't match the form of my regex - I do not have much experience with regex, for creating the above one I had to do long and intense research - and so I could not modify my regex, referring to these]

[The regex is should allow digits, optional decimal point and optional minus]

Thx in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers. Use `/-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g`

Comment: any feedback? Could you provide a fiddle if it does not?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it works well (I use the first version). It is really handy if you have to extract the positive/negative values from css via javascript. [I just haven't given any feedback by now, because I thought, in the terms of Stackoverflow was something like "do not post comments just to thank" or something like that. Correct me if I'm wrong. In any case: Great solution :)  )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
/-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nV9qJ3/1)

**Explanation**:

- `-?` - an optional hyphen (you may replace it with `[-+]?` to match both `-` and `+` optionally)
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits.