# How do I determine retrieved value type in Java?

Tags: java

Having searched unsuccessfully for days, I thought I would ask.

I am retrieving a value from a table, whose columns are all varchar.  How do we go about identifying the type of value.  For e.g.

accountnumber may have values such as `123456`, `123456:78910`

```
    ...
    try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table")){
      if(rs.next()){
        //Cannot use anything other than 'getString'
        String var = rs.getString("accountnumber");                 
        //Determine if var is an Integer
        System.out.println(var instanceof Integer)  //returns false because 'var' is of type String.
      }
    }
   ...
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if the String could be converted to a number or not?  Try parsing it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - `parse` seems to be the way to go.  I completely forgot about that.

Comment: Note Integer.parseInt(String0 will only parse `int` values.  You might want Long.parseLong(String) or BigInteger.valueOf(String) for larger integers.

Answer (score 2):

The thing works as intended. The columns are typed as varchar in the schema, so the database and the Java SQL interface can't know if you actually have numbers or names or dates or whatever stored inside. Only `getString` should work.

It's up to you to try to parse the string results in ways that make sense.

For example, the `Integer.parseInt` method would transform a string to an integer, or throw an exception if it cannot. There's equivalent versions for `Long` or `Double` etc.

However, looking at the example accountnumbers, they aren't really integers, but rather have a more complex structure. You might want to model that with a class with two fields (primaryAccountNumber, theOtherAccountNumber) etc, and it should take care of parsing.

---

On a different note, you should never `select *` from a database, but rather be explicit about the fields that you need. This protects against schema changes which remove fields you were dependent on (the select will fail, instead of some code later down the line), or pulling in too much data and just using a bit of it.

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSet#getMetaData();` will give you the required informations.
`ResultMetaData` has some methods that will help eg.  [getColumnType(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType(int)) or [getColumnClassName(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnClassName(int))

Comment: This won't work because all the columns are varchar. Even a date value, numbers are all stored in varchar.

Comment: @Bala then you have big, big problem. You will have to manually eg. try to convert value to Integer, if it fails, try to convert/read is as date, if it fails, ..... so on so on till you finally run out of possible data types and MAYBE you will succeed.

Comment: @Bala my best bet would be to ask database designer how to "guess column type" efficiently ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern matching` to check its a number or a string.

```
  String var = rs.getString("accountnumber");
  Matcher ss1 = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*)").matcher(var);
  if (ss1.matches()) {
      // its a number
  } else {
      // its a string
  }
```

Comment: tht can be get from this ques : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers

Comment: For checking floating point number , just the regular expression needs to be changed, the regex can be get from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers

Comment: @Antoniossss It's known to be an integer, but it could be negative.