# Separating number and unit in a string in C#

Tags: c#, c++, regex, string, scanf

I have to write an equivalent of this in C++ in C#,

```
string val_in;
float val;
char unit[100];

val_in = NoSpace(val_in);

int nscan = sscanf(val_in.c_str(), "%f%s", &val, &unit);

if (nscan < 2) {
    return val_in; //do nothing if scan fail
}
```

where the `NoSpace()` method trims and removes all spaces in `val_in`.

I have looked around here on SO and most of the similar questions involves strings that contain delimiters such as spaces or commas, but don't apply to this case. So I turned to RegEx.

So far, I have this,

```
string val_in;
float val;
char[] unit = new char[100];

string[] val_arr;

val_in = NoSpace(val_in);

val_arr = Regex.Split(val_in, @"([-]?\d*\.?\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)");
val = Single.Parse(val_arr[1]);

if (val_arr.Length < 2) {
    return val_in; //do nothing if scan fail
}
```

It works so far, but I was wondering if there is another way to do this? I a bit wary of RegEx, because according the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers0), having `([-]?\d*\.?\d+)` instead of `([-]?(\d*\.)?\d+)` is potentially dangerous because of evil RegEx. But if I include those extra parenthesis, then I have an extra group. This causes `Split()` to split something like `123.456miles` into an array with the elements,

```
{emptystr, 123.456, 123., miles}
```

This way, I can't be sure that the unit, `miles` in this case, will be in `val_arr[2]`, which is a problem.

I tested this on [this .NET RegEx tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester). I also tried to break my RegEx pattern, `([-]?\d*\.?\d+)`, but it seems to be fine and "evil RegEx safe". So I'm not sure if I should stick to what I've done so far, or find a more elegant solution, if one exist.

Comment: What's this got to do with C#?

Comment: Oh my goodness sorry. I forgot to say that I have to rewrite that C++ snippet in C#. Edited.

Comment: The C++ code is supposed to take string of a number and a unit, I believe just in "miles" or "Km" (though there may be variations, and I can't be sure at this point) and separate it into `float val` and `string unit`. I am trying to do something similar in my C# code, where the RegEx pattern will split `val_in` into a string array, then I can take `val_arr[1]` as "val" and `val_arr[2]` as "unit".

Comment: This question seems to be pretty badly received so far. I apologize if I haven't been clear enough. The RegEx pattern is supposed to take things like `123`, `123.456` and `.456` but will not match things like `123.` and `12.34.56`.

Comment: An example input would be `string val_in = 123.456miles`. In the C++ code, this string would be split into `float val = 123.456` and `string unit = "miles"`.

Comment: Is your question about splitting a string into two parts, or about a regex pattern that validates a string prior to splitting it??

Comment: Both. I want to make sure I'm not taking the long way round, and if I'm not, I want to make sure that the pattern is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but can't you just look for the first letter in the string to know where your unit starts?

```
  static void SplitValAndUnit(string unsplitData)
  {
     for (int x = 0; x < unsplitData.Length; x++)
     {
        if (Char.IsLetter(unsplitData[x]))
        {
           string value = unsplitData.Substring(0, x);
           // TryParse value to whatever data type
           string unit  = unsplitData.Substring(x, unsplitData.Length - x);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Note: The `Char.IsLetter` check can be replaced with a `RegEx` check to account for strange characters still considered letters