# Flutter: Validating floats

Tags: validation, flutter

I'm trying to get dart to validate a float that my user will enter in my form. I took the guidance from this SO thread ([Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers/12643073?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) on Regex expressions for floating point numbers (for eg, 12.830), and tried it in my flutter app.

```
new TextFormField(
                        controller:  amt_invested,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp(r'[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+'))],
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: CupertinoColors.white,
                            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Amount invested',
                            prefixText: '\R',
                            suffixText: 'ZAR',
                            suffixStyle:
                            const TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Amount is required' : null,
                      ),
```

However, the regex is preventing me from entering the full-stop in the float, contrary to what the SO thread said. How do I get this to work properly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll down a few lines in the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers/12643073) to the section *if you want to match `123.`*

Here, you do want to match `123.` as it's a stepping stone on the way to `123.45`.

So, change your RegExp to `new RegExp(r'^[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)$');` As you are using a numeric keypad, you could probably dispense with the leading `^` and trailing `$`

This example

```
main() {
  RegExp re;

  re = new RegExp(r'[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+');
  print(test(re, '1234'));
  print(test(re, '1234.'));
  print(test(re, '1234.5'));
  print(test(re, '1234a'));
  print(test(re, '1234..'));

  print('---');

  re = new RegExp(r'^[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)$');
  print(test(re, '1234'));
  print(test(re, '1234.'));
  print(test(re, '1234.5'));
  print(test(re, '1234a'));
  print(test(re, '1234..'));
  print(test(re, '1234 '));
}
```

outputs

```
true
false <- this causes your problem
true
false
false
---
true
true
true
false
false
false
```