# How can I split text and number in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below data and want to separate the float value and string value using MySQL.

```
number_column
122.33
123.44
15.44
x-mas
lax
closed
```

I just want float value. I want to remove the string value from there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, show us what you have tried so far. I mean some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match the characters that appear in floating point numbers.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE number_column RLIKE '^[-0-9.]+$'
```

Note that this simple regexp doesn't actually check for valid numeric syntax; it will allow `1.2.3` or `3-2`. If you need a more accurate regular expression, see [Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)