# Regular Expression: Matching decimals in Javascript (for non-string variables)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match decimals for both strings and floats. Noticed that the below RegEx matches floats ending with a period(.) as well which isn't expected.

```js
const regex = RegExp("^(\\d*\\.)?\\d+$");
arrTest = ["3.", 3., "4.", 4., "5.5", 5.5];

arrTest.forEach(element => {
    console.log(regex.test(element)) 
});
/*
Result
=======
"3."  - False
 3.   - True (Expecting false since regex should end with a number)
"4."  - False
 4.   - True (Expecting false since regex should end with a number)
"5.5" - True
 5.5  - True
*/
```

Comment: `\\d*\\.` - you allow any amount of digits before the dot, including no digits. Just use `+` for one or more and make the dot and rest of the digits optional.

Comment: `3.` is evaluated to `"3"` and it matches your regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: Also look at [this article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) on regular expressions for floating point numbers.

Comment: Change `console.log(regex.test(element))` with `console.log(element + ': ' + regex.test(element))` and analyse the output.

Answer (score 0):

`3.` is `3`.

RegExp pattern matching uses *strings*.  Anything you pass will be first converted to a string.  You cannot write `3.` in your JavaScript code and not have that evaluate to the number `3`, and therefore become `"3"` when converted to a string.