# (C++) How do I display an error when more than one "." is used in a calcualtor?

Tags: c++

I am making a calculator using command line arguments, and one of the problems I am having is that I can't find a way to display an error to inputs that have more than one ".". 3.33 can be accepted, but 3.3.3.2 cannot because its an invalid number.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc == 1) {

    cout << "E\n";
    return 0;
  }
  if (argc <= 2) {
    cout << "P\n";
    return 0;
  }
  if (argc > 4) {
    cout << "P\n";
    return 0;
  }

  if (argc == 3) {
    cout << endl << (atof(argv[1]) + atof(argv[2])) << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  else if (argc == 4) {
    // Addition operation
    if (argv[3][0] == 'a')
      cout << endl << (atoi(argv[1]) + atoi(argv[2])) << endl;

    // Subtraction operation
    else if (argv[3][0] == 's')
      cout << endl << (atof(argv[1]) - atof(argv[2])) << endl;

    // Multiplication operation
    else if (argv[3][0] == 'm')
      cout << endl << (atof(argv[1]) * atof(argv[2])) << endl;

    // Division operation
    else if (argv[3][0] == 'd')
      if (argv[2][0] == '0') {
        cout << endl << "error";
        return 0;
      } else {
        cout << endl << (atof(argv[1]) / atof(argv[2])) << endl;
      }

    // Exponential operation
    else if (argv[3][0] == 'p')
      if (argv[2][0] > -1.00 && argv[2][0] < 1.00) {
        cout << endl << "Y";
        return 0;
      } else if (argv[1][0] == '-') {
        cout << endl << "Y";
        return 0;
      }

      else
        cout << endl << pow(atof(argv[1]), atof(argv[2])) << endl;

    else
      cout << endl << "V" << endl;
    // Any other operator
  }
}
```

Comment: This is clearly C++ code. Don't use the C tag, that's a different language.

Comment: Please don't spam the tags, this question has nothing to do with `c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way for checking the validity of a string is to use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), for example, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643073/1383356).

You can write something like this to extract your operands:

```cpp
float op1, op2;
std::string p1 = argv[1];
std::string p2 = argv[2];
std::regex pattern("[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+");

if (std::regex_match(p1, pattern) && 
    std::regex_match(p2, pattern)) {
  op1 = atof(argv[1]);
  op2 = atof(argv[2]);
  // ...
} else {
  cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the return value of [atof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) to check if an error happened:

> Return value
>
> Floating point value corresponding to the contents of str
> on success. If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding
> return type, range error occurs and HUGE_VAL, HUGE_VALF or HUGE_VALL
> is returned. If no conversion can be performed, ​0​ is returned and
> *str_end is set to str.

Answer (score 1):

`atof` will stop when it finds characters that cannot be part of the floating point number, and this includes an extra '.'. Unfortunately it does not tell you this happened.

Smarter conversion functions like  [`std::stof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) or [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) will notify you if the entire string was not consumed when parsing.

Example:

```cpp
size_t end;
float val = std::stof(argv[1], &end);
if (end != strlen(argv[1]))
{
    cout << "Bad input: " << argv[1] << "\n"; 
    return -1; 
}
```

will return from `main` and exit the program if the entire argument is not consumed when parsing or throw an exception if the number was out of range or  no number could be parsed, ending the program if uncaught.

```cpp
char * endp; 
errno = 0;
float val = strtof(argv[1], &endp); 
if (*endp != '\0' || errno = ERANGE) 
{ 
    cout << "Bad input: " << argv[1] << "\n"; 
    return -1; 
}
```

will return from `main` and exit the program if the entire argument is not consumed when parsing or the number was out of range. I personally prefer this option because I don't like throwing exceptions over user input. Users getting the input wrong is not exceptional enough to be worth an exception.

If your compiler is up to date, [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) can be extremely helpful. The linked documentation provides excellent examples of its usage.