# Alternative to try/pass - python

Tags: python

```
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return 0
```

So this function uses the try except statement but is there an alternative way of doing this??

Comment: What sort of alternative are you looking for?

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what type of variable x is?

Comment: This looks perfectly fine. You could improve it by catching a specific exception like `except ValueError`.

Comment: You could use https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress in some cases.

Comment: Override the float class /:

Comment: Returning 0 is potentially ambiguous. Surely you'd want to know if *x* was a valid string representation of a (potentially) floating point number. Of course you may want zero as default in which case your code is fine (notwithstanding the unqualified *except* clause). Personally I would either allow the exception to propagate or return None - but that's very much a matter of opinion

Answer (score 0):

Try/except seems like to simplest and best solution, but you could use an `if` statement similar to this:

```
if str(x).lstrip('-').replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
    return float(x)
return 0
```

The if statement will remove `-` if it's a negative number and exactly one `.` from the input and then check there is only digits left. It converts it to a string first so we can use `.replace()`.

There are still possibilities of exceptions like mentioned in the comments if `x == '²'`

Comment: This may not be reliable. Consider what happens when *x == '-1.5'* The decimal point would be removed and isdigit() would return False yet *float('-1.5')* is perfectly legal

Comment: ...and on the other hand, this code can still raise an exception, e.g. when `x == '²'`

Comment: Good points. I added an `lstrip` to take care of negative numbers, but I don't see any way of taking care of unlikely inputs like `x == '²'` without try/except.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it would work but I would always make sure to define the exception you are trying to catch.  In this case `ValueError`
Another way to write this would be

```
def func(x):
    try:
        y = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
    # do some more with y if it was changed to a float
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x is a str, you could use regex to see if that str is formatted properly to be cast as a float.

```py
import re

float_regex = re.compile(r"^-?(\d*\.)?\d+$")

if float_regex.match(x):
    return float(x)
return 0
```

- The `^ ... $` at beginning and end ensure that the match isn't a substring and that the full string can only contain the inner regex. The string must start and stop exactly as defined.
- `-?` allows an optional minus sign
- `(\d*\.)?` optionally allows a digit followed by a decimal
- `\d+` requires at least 1 digit

See here for more details on the regex expression used: https://regex101.com/r/3RXmM1/1

All of this being said, use your original code, except make sure you only catch the ValueError exception. Using regex is overkill here unless you have a specific reason. If python can't cast as a float then just let it do the work for you.

Comment: There are other formats for floats, like scientific notation and "inf", "nan", ...etc. Also an ending point is allowed: `3.` ... and more.

Comment: @trincot yeah I mean it depends how many bases you want to cover. I still think the try/except is the best option and it's certainly what I'd use.

Comment: See here as well for more discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers

Answer (score 0):

As @jornsharpe suggested in the comments

```
from contextlib import suppress
x = "abc"
res= None
with suppress(ValueError):
    res = float(x)
if not isinstance(res, float):
    res = 0
print(res) # 0
```

But still not a good thind to suppress the Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine; using `try/catch` is promoted among Python coders.

Just as an exercise, I thought I'd follow the definitions in the documentation for the [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) function and the lexical analysis section on [floating point literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating). From those we can derive the following regular expression:

```
import re

reFloat = re.compile(r"(?i)^\s*[+-]?(((\d(_?\d)*)?\.\d(_?\d)*|\d(_?\d)*\.?)(e[+-]?\d(_?\d)*)?|nan|inf(inity)?)\s*$")
```

We can then define this function:

```
safeFloat = lambda x, default=0: float(x) if reFloat.match(x) else default
```

I believe this function will call `float` if, and only when, `float(x)` would not raise an exception, provided `x` is a string.

Some tests:

```
good = ["-3.14", "10.", ".001", "+1e100", "3.14e-10", "0e0", " 3.14_15_93  ", "+NaN", "  -Infinity\n\f\r\t "]

for x in good:
    print(x.strip(), safeFloat(x))

bad = [".", "_345", "123_", "e13", "123e", "- 1", "5-3", "1e3.4", "Infinit"]

for x in bad:
    print(x.strip(), safeFloat(x))  # Always 0
```