# Allow more digit after the first 0 with live input validation regex

Tags: regex, numeric

I have a regex for some verification on my end. It is

```
^(?![.,])-?[1-9]*?0?[,.]?([,.]\d+)?$
```

This regex basically validates a number

- if it starts with **0**, a comma or dot must follow

  - Valid => **0.12** or **0,456**
  - Invalid => 012.90
- cannot have multiple dot or comma in a row e.g. **12..45**
- can only a digit or a comma or a dot e.g. 123, 123.45 or 123,45
- can't start and end with a dot or comma

This regex perfectly works for above points but I got stuck on one case which is I can't type a number like **100** or **101** because it still expects me a dot or comma as regex still treats any zero as the first rule. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you rephrase `can only a digit or a comma or dot`? Could you provide 5 or 10 examples of what is/isn't valid? Is `0` alone valid?

Comment: @user3783243 the input can only be consist of a number or a dot or a comma I mean e.g. 100.45 or 50,66 or 12345

Comment: So you just want to check that input is a number and can have decimal notation as comma or period?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: @JorgeCampos That regexp allows leading zeroes, which aren't allowed here except when it's the only digit before the decimal.

Comment: Fair enough, will retract the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos tbh I didn't think this like that. I found better regex out there but now there is another issue. Now using your example I can type 012 but I don't want to allow any digit if there is a leading zero before the decimal point

Comment: So maybe this one: `^(0[,.]\d+|\d+|([1-9]+([,.]\d+)?))$` https://regex101.com/r/PT1mx5/1

Comment: Your regex is written with live input validation in mind, and if it is true, you cannot actually check "*can't start and end with a dot or comma*" condition as you would not be able to input a comma/dot. A `^(?:0(?:[,.]\d*)?|[1-9]\d*(?:[,.]\d*)?)$` [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/yQF8fM/1) would be something you would consider then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew man you always outmatches everyone when it comes to regexes \o/. Yours is almost right except for the case `56.` (or comma) which is matching. https://regex101.com/r/r9fh8C/1 Thanks for this anyways.

Comment: @JorgeCampos actually 56. is a valid case for me because as Wiktor mentioned this is a check for live typing :) BTW that works like a charm, thanks a lot! Would you mind posting it as an answer so I could mark as solved?

Comment: Awesome! Lets wait for him to add it as an answer then. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not sure who decided on this is a dupe of another question. I am afraid they don't have an understanding of both questions. Btw answer in the other post, it still allows 012 :)

Comment: This is the regex that describes your specifications **^(?!.*[,.]{2})(?![.,]|.*[.,]$)(?=(?:[\d,]+|[\d.]+)$)(?:0[,.]|[1-9])[\d,.]+$**. Why is this a duplicate ? Well now this can't be explained now, but this is the solution.

Comment: I think `^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:[.,]\d*)?$` would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Yeah, it is my regex facored in, it does the same thing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew would you be kind adding your comment as an answer so I could mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:[.,]\d*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CtguM/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` - either

  - `0` - zero
  - `|` - or
  - `[1-9]\d*` - one to nine digit and then any zero or more digits
- `(?:[.,]\d*)?` - an optional sequence of a comma or dot and then zero or more digits.
- `$` - end of string.