# Parse javascript value from HTML response in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, parsing, variables

I'm actually building an application where by using an HttpClient in .NET 4.5, I send a GET request to a webpage (which isn't mine) and I receive this response in the Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:widget="http://www.netvibes.com/ns/">
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" 
      content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script><title>Site</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var HOST_DOMAIN = 'http://www.site.com/';
var ID = '2261443944';
var BASE_URL = 'https://base.site.com';
</script>

  </head>
    <body >
    </body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do is somehow Parse the values HOST_DOMAIN, ID and BASE_URL from the js script in the head section using .NET 4.5 libraries, but I can't find how. Any ideas?

Comment: You could simply use a regular expression like `var HOST_DOMAIN = '([^']+)';`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228630.aspx

Comment: @Yogu By using a regular expression I can only see IF the above string is included in my reply, and not store it's value ('http://www.site.com/') in a variable. However, i'm not too experienced in Regex, so if you could expand your answer, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression that captures the url in a group.

```
  string pattern = @"var HOST_DOMAIN = '([^']+)';";
  Match match = Regex.Matches(html, pattern)).FirstOrDefault();
  if (match != null)
      return match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Explanation: The parenthesis define a group in the regular expression that gets stored in the `Groups` properties of the match.

Possible problem: does not work if the url contains escaped apostrophs.

Answer (score 0):

For regex for host name use

```
var ValidHostnameRegex = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";
```

Refer link : [Stack Overflow Hostname Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Then for a number use 
[Reg Ex Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011524/javascript-regexp-number-only-check)

and how to use reg ex in javascript 
[How to use regex in js](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/using_regexregular_expressions_in_javascript.aspx)