# Validate comma separated numbers with positive/negative integers and float

Tags: javascript

I need a regular expression for a comma separated values, that accept positive/negative integer and also float numbers.

Ej: 3,45,2.5,12,-20

How do I get it? Thanks

I need to implement a function that adds values and returns the result, and it detects a pattern of incorrect entry such numbers separated by hyphens

Ej: 3,45,2.5,12,-20 (Correct)

Ej: 3-45-2.5-12-20 (Incorrect)

but I do not get it, the code I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validar()
{
var patron = /^(-?\d*\.?\d*,?)+$/;                         
var numeros = document.getElementById("numeros").value;

if (!patron.test(numeros)) 
{        
    alert("Introduzca los números que desee sumar separados por comas, Ej: 3,3.25,-1");                      
}
else 
{
    suma();     
}
} 

function suma()
{
var entrada = document.getElementById("numeros").value;
var numeros = entrada.split(",");
var suma = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
    {
        suma += parseFloat(numeros[i]);
    }
document.getElementById("resultado").value = suma;
}    
</script>
</head>
<body>
Números: <input type="text" id="numeros" size="30">
Resultado: <input type="text" id="resultado" size="20">
<input type="button" value="SUMAR" onClick="validar()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011524/javascript-regexp-number-only-check) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396084/regex-for-comma-delimited-list).

```
"3,45,2.5,12,-20".split(",").every( 
    function(x) { return /^-?\d*\.?\d*$/.test(x); }
);
```

Or as single regex

```
/^(-?\d*\.?\d*)(,-?\d*\.?\d*)*$/.test("3,45,2.5,12,-20")
```

After a bit of refactoring you will get

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>JS Números</title>
</head>

<body>
Números: <input type="text" id="numeros" size="30">
Resultado: <input type="text" id="resultado" size="20">
<input type="button" value="SUMAR" onClick="suma()">

<script type="text/javascript">
var numberElement = document.getElementById("numeros");
var resultElement = document.getElementById("resultado");
var numberPattern = /^(-?\d*\.?\d*)(,-?\d*\.?\d*)*$/;

function suma() {
    var numberString = numberElement.value;
    if (numberPattern.test(numberString)) {
        var sum = numberString.split(",").reduce(function(m,v) { return m + parseFloat(v); }, 0);
        resultElement.value = sum;
    } else {
        alert("Introduzca los números que desee sumar separados por comas, Ej: 3,3.25,-1");
        resultElement.value = "";
    }
}    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```