# Show popover on text box if value is exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am new in javascript. I have no idea of javascript and I am still learning. I want a small help.
I have a label with a number. The user has to manually enter a number in a textbox. If the value entered by the user exceeds the value written in the label,a popover should be shown over the input box.
I tried to do it but the popover is shown anyways. I want the popover to be shown only if condition is met.
Also,Can anyone please tell me how can I include anchor tag and `<br>` tag in popover content?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Err2 = $("#max").val();
  $('input').blur(function(){
    if( $(this).val() >= Err2 ) {
      $(this).popover({
        title: 'Warning!',
        content: 'sfgjksfhgjkhdghdfgjkdfjkgdfjkgn <a href=#">fgdfgdg</a>jhksdjhfdfsdgjlk',
        placement: 'bottom'
      }).popover('show');
    } else {
      $(this).popover('destroy');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
content=<span id="max">5</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

http://www.bootply.com/suPp4ThGxq

Answer (score 1):

First, `span` do not have `value` property. So `$("#max").val()` will return `""`

Secound, when you read value from DOM element, they are read as string. Its is best if you use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to check.

[Updated Code](http://www.bootply.com/bQKHBQ6rI7)

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the `var Err2 = $("#max").val();` with `var Err2 = $("#max").text();`

for span it returns "" for val()

Answer (score 0):

Use `text()` instead of `val()` like this :

```
var Err2=$("#max").text();
```

Also, you will have to test if you get numbers or text in your field.

See this post to test if a field contains numbers : [Javascript regexp number only check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011524/javascript-regexp-number-only-check)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your script with the one below it will work as you have expected.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Err2 = $("#max").text();
  $('input').keyup(function(){
    if( $(this).val().length >= Err2 ) {
      $(this).popover({
        title: 'Warning!',
        content: 'sfgjksfhgjkhdghdfgjkdfjkgdfjkgn <a href=#">fgdfgdg</a>jhksdjhfdfsdgjlk',
        placement: 'bottom'
      }).popover('show');
    } else {
      $(this).popover('destroy');
    }
  })
});
</script>
```