# Javascript regex pattern for specific case

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex pattern to get all the numbers from this **"id=1,6,a"**

In this case what i need to get is 1 and 6. In case there is a floating number I want to ignore it

Comment: define number, is `a` a number in this case ? Do you mean digit and if so do you mean decimal digit or hex?

Comment: what I want to get is 1 and 6. I need to split it to get only 1 and 6 and I only want whole number I want to ignore the floating numbers

Comment: Add an example of what you have tried, even if it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplication: [Javascript regexp number only check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011524/javascript-regexp-number-only-check)

Comment: I tried this one **/(?:id=)([\d])/**

Comment: You can use `match`. `str.match(/\d+/g)`. To get the values in Number format `str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to split it to get only 1 and 6 and I only want whole number I
>   want to ignore the floating numbers

You can use `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/\D|\d+\.\d+/` to split characters that are not digits, or digits followed by `.` character followed by digits to handle for example `2.456`, `Array.prototype.filter()` with parameter `Boolean` to remove empty strings from result

```js
console.log("id=1,6,a,2.456".split(/\D|\d+\.\d+/).filter(Boolean))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
RegExp: /([0-9]*[0-9])/gm
pattern: ([0-9]*[0-9])
flags: gm
1 capturing groups: 
   group 1: ([0-9]*[0-9])
```

See more at: http://regexr.com/v1?393a1

Option 2:

```
RegExp: /(\d+)/gm
pattern: (\d+)
flags: gm
1 capturing groups: 
  group 1: (\d+)
```

See more at: http://regexr.com/v1?393a4

thanks **p.s.w.g**

But please try to research before asking anything.

Comment: `/a*a/` is equivalent to `/a+/`, and `/[0-9]/` is equivalent to `/\d/` (in JavaScript anyway).