# Select td containing number

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, html-table

I'm trying to use jQuery to add classes to a table for a Wordpress site. I've had luck using nth-child(number) for selecting a specific td containing specific info. However, some cells/td's are containing several different information, so I want to select and target based on what they contain. Specifically, I want to select a td based on that it starts with or contains a number, but I can't figure out a way to do this. 
I've tried using different if statements, but can't get it to work.

Here's the code I use for the other cells, which contains the same information throughout the table:

```
$( "td:nth-child(5)" ).not( "td:empty" ).addClass("wine-currency");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this, you'll have to use `.filter()` and test the contents.

Comment: Care to elaborate on how to or point me in a direction where I can figure it out? I'm still really green in jquery.

Comment: This may help, you could give a try to [the includes() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Comment: I told you the exact function to use. I don't see how I can point you more in the direction without just doing it for you entirely.

Comment: In the filter function, use `.text()` to get the text of the TD, and use a regular expression to test if it contains a number.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL `includes()` needs a specific string to search for, he wants to match any number. This is a job for a regular expression.

Comment: [Then this is his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011524/javascript-regexp-number-only-check?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Found a way, thanks for helping out!