# Format telephone and credit card numbers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, number-formatting

**Question one (formatting telephone number):**

I'm having to format a telephone number in AngularJS but there is no filter for it. Is there a way to use filter or currency to format 10 digits to `(555) 555-5255`? and still preserve the data type of the field as integer?

**Question two (masking credit card number):**

I have a credit card field that is mapped to AngularJS, like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customer.creditCardNumber">
```

which is returning the whole number (`4111111111111111`). I will like to mask it with xxx the first 12 digits and only show the last 4. I was thinking on using filter: limit for this but am not clear as how. Any ideas? Is there a way to also format the number with dashes but still retain the data type as integer? sort of `4111-1111-1111-1111`.

Comment: Phone numbers and credit card numbers are both complicated constructs that potentially require complicated UI. They each deserve their own question, rather than being rolled into one like this.

Comment: About your question one: Don't use integer as data type in non-numeric fields. Telephones, zip codes and document numbers are not numeric (you'll never do any math with them) and are better treated as strings.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Also, if you need to format telephone number on output only, you can use a custom filter like this one:

```
angular.module('ng').filter('tel', function () {
    return function (tel) {
        if (!tel) { return ''; }

        var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

        if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
            return tel;
        }

        var country, city, number;

        switch (value.length) {
            case 10: // +1PPP####### -> C (PPP) ###-####
                country = 1;
                city = value.slice(0, 3);
                number = value.slice(3);
                break;

            case 11: // +CPPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
                country = value[0];
                city = value.slice(1, 4);
                number = value.slice(4);
                break;

            case 12: // +CCCPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
                country = value.slice(0, 3);
                city = value.slice(3, 5);
                number = value.slice(5);
                break;

            default:
                return tel;
        }

        if (country == 1) {
            country = "";
        }

        number = number.slice(0, 3) + '-' + number.slice(3);

        return (country + " (" + city + ") " + number).trim();
    };
});
```

Then you can use this filter in your template:

```
{{ phoneNumber | tel }}
<span ng-bind="phoneNumber | tel"></span>
```

Comment: I went ahead and tried as a fiddle but there is something missing that I can't figure out. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/jorgecas99/S7aSj/

Comment: works like a charm! It was my fault, I had some typos in there. Here is the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jorgecas99/S7aSj/

Comment: the function is great. can you use the filter in an input ng bind? had no applying it to the input. for that I used ui-mask and it's less elegant :/

Comment: J Castill, at line 36 of your fiddle, I would do: country = 1 ? "" : country;

Comment: Still a little broken for international numbers.

Comment: You now need to do "app.filter()", you cannot attach anything to 'ng' any more. See:  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr

Comment: How to make it work for +1 123 1234 and 800 numbers 1 800 123 1234 ?

Answer (score 21):

I created an AngularJS module to handle this issue regarding phonenumbers for myself with a custom directive and accompanying filter.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/aberke/s0xpkgmq/

Filter use example:
    `<p>{{ phonenumberValue | phonenumber }}</p>`

Filter code:

```
.filter('phonenumber', function() {
    /* 
    Format phonenumber as: c (xxx) xxx-xxxx
        or as close as possible if phonenumber length is not 10
        if c is not '1' (country code not USA), does not use country code
    */

    return function (number) {
        /* 
        @param {Number | String} number - Number that will be formatted as telephone number
        Returns formatted number: (###) ###-####
            if number.length < 4: ###
            else if number.length < 7: (###) ###

        Does not handle country codes that are not '1' (USA)
        */
        if (!number) { return ''; }

        number = String(number);

        // Will return formattedNumber. 
        // If phonenumber isn't longer than an area code, just show number
        var formattedNumber = number;

        // if the first character is '1', strip it out and add it back
        var c = (number[0] == '1') ? '1 ' : '';
        number = number[0] == '1' ? number.slice(1) : number;

        // # (###) ###-#### as c (area) front-end
        var area = number.substring(0,3);
        var front = number.substring(3, 6);
        var end = number.substring(6, 10);

        if (front) {
            formattedNumber = (c + "(" + area + ") " + front);  
        }
        if (end) {
            formattedNumber += ("-" + end);
        }
        return formattedNumber;
    };
});
```

Directive use example:

```
<phonenumber-directive placeholder="'Input phonenumber here'" model='myModel.phonenumber'></phonenumber-directive>
```

Directive code:

```
.directive('phonenumberDirective', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    /*
    Intended use:
        <phonenumber-directive placeholder='prompt' model='someModel.phonenumber'></phonenumber-directive>
    Where:
        someModel.phonenumber: {String} value which to bind only the numeric characters [0-9] entered
            ie, if user enters 617-2223333, value of 6172223333 will be bound to model
        prompt: {String} text to keep in placeholder when no numeric input entered
    */

    function link(scope, element, attributes) {

        // scope.inputValue is the value of input element used in template
        scope.inputValue = scope.phonenumberModel;

        scope.$watch('inputValue', function(value, oldValue) {

            value = String(value);
            var number = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
            scope.phonenumberModel = number;
            scope.inputValue = $filter('phonenumber')(number);
        });
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            phonenumberPlaceholder: '=placeholder',
            phonenumberModel: '=model',
        },
        // templateUrl: '/static/phonenumberModule/template.html',
        template: '<input ng-model="inputValue" type="tel" class="phonenumber" placeholder="{{phonenumberPlaceholder}}" title="Phonenumber (Format: (999) 9999-9999)">',
    };
}])
```

Full code with module and how to use it:
https://gist.github.com/aberke/042eef0f37dba1138f9e

Comment: When I save my form and open it again the number is not getting saved.Do you hav eany idea y it is happening?

Answer (score 13):

As shailbenq suggested, [phoneformat](https://github.com/albeebe/phoneformat.js) is awesome.

Include phone format in your website. Create a filter for the angular module or your application.

```
angular.module('ng')
.filter('tel', function () {
    return function (phoneNumber) {
        if (!phoneNumber)
            return phoneNumber;

        return formatLocal('US', phoneNumber); 
    }
});
```

Then you can use the filter in your HTML.

```
{{phone|tel}} 
OR
<span ng-bind="phone|tel"></span>
```

If you want to use the filter in your controller.

```
var number = '5553219876';
var newNumber = $filter('tel')(number);
```

Comment: unless for i18n, I prefer AngularUI's ui.mask

Answer (score 11):

[image]

I also found that JQuery plugin that is easy to include in your Angular App (also with bower :D ) and which check all possible country codes with their respective masks :
[intl-tel-input](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input)

You can then use the `validationScript` option in order to check the validity of the input's value.

Comment: is their any options to remove jquery plugin?

Answer (score 6):

This is the simple way. As basic I took it from http://codepen.io/rpdasilva/pen/DpbFf, and done some changes. For now code is more simply.
And you can get: in controller - "**4124561232**", in view "**(412) 456-1232**"

Filter:

```
myApp.filter 'tel', ->
  (tel) ->
    if !tel
      return ''
    value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '')

    city = undefined
    number = undefined
    res = null
    switch value.length
      when 1, 2, 3
        city = value
      else
        city = value.slice(0, 3)
        number = value.slice(3)
    if number
      if number.length > 3
        number = number.slice(0, 3) + '-' + number.slice(3, 7)
      else
        number = number
      res = ('(' + city + ') ' + number).trim()
    else
      res = '(' + city
    return res
```

And directive:

```
myApp.directive 'phoneInput', ($filter, $browser) ->

  require: 'ngModel'
  scope:
    phone: '=ngModel'
  link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->

    $scope.$watch "phone", (newVal, oldVal) ->
      value = newVal.toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice 0, 10
      $scope.phone = value
      $element.val $filter('tel')(value, false)
      return
    return
```

Answer (score 5):

Angular-ui has a directive for masking input. Maybe this is what you want for masking (unfortunately, the documentation isn't that great):

http://angular-ui.github.com/

I don't think this will help with obfuscating the credit card number, though.

Comment: Try this for documentation: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-utils.html. Ignore the mask.js and 'ui.mask' part. Instead use ui.utils.js and 'ui.utils' while adding dependency.

Comment: If the documentation is not that great, provide a working example to overcome that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You also can check **input mask formatter**.

This is a directive and it's called `ui-mask` and also it's a part of [`angular-ui.utils`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/mask) library.

Here is working: **[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hcRp9b4YeRJX0dVddmZ6?p=preview)**

> For the time of writing this post there aren't any examples of using this directive, so I've made a very **simple example** to demonstrate how this thing works in practice.

Comment: Heres a fantastic example from them: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Try using phoneformat.js (http://www.phoneformat.com/), you can not only format phone number based on user locales (en-US, ja-JP, fr-FR, de-DE etc) but it also validates the phone number. Its very robust library based on googles libphonenumber project.

Answer (score 2):

I took aberke's solution and modified it to suit my taste.

- It produces a single input element
- It optionally accepts extensions
- For US numbers it skips the leading country code
- Standard naming conventions
- Uses class from using code; doesn't make up a class
- Allows use of any other attributes allowed on an input element

My [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/tmorrow-hyphensolutions/pen/pjeYLK?editors=101)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('exampleController',
  function exampleController($scope) {
    $scope.user = { profile: {HomePhone: '(719) 465-0001 x1234'}};
    $scope.homePhonePrompt = "Home Phone";
  });

myApp
/*
    Intended use:
    <phone-number placeholder='prompt' model='someModel.phonenumber' />
    Where: 
      someModel.phonenumber: {String} value which to bind formatted or unformatted phone number

    prompt: {String} text to keep in placeholder when no numeric input entered
*/
.directive('phoneNumber',
  ['$filter',
  function ($filter) {
    function link(scope, element, attributes) {

      // scope.inputValue is the value of input element used in template
      scope.inputValue = scope.phoneNumberModel;

      scope.$watch('inputValue', function (value, oldValue) {

        value = String(value);
        var number = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
        scope.inputValue = $filter('phoneNumber')(number, scope.allowExtension);
        scope.phoneNumberModel = scope.inputValue;
      });
    }

    return {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        phoneNumberPlaceholder: '@placeholder',
        phoneNumberModel: '=model',
        allowExtension: '=extension'
      },
      template: '<input ng-model="inputValue" type="tel" placeholder="{{phoneNumberPlaceholder}}" />'
    };
  }
  ]
)
/* 
    Format phonenumber as: (aaa) ppp-nnnnxeeeee
    or as close as possible if phonenumber length is not 10
    does not allow country code or extensions > 5 characters long
*/
.filter('phoneNumber', 
  function() {
    return function(number, allowExtension) {
      /* 
      @param {Number | String} number - Number that will be formatted as telephone number
      Returns formatted number: (###) ###-#### x #####
      if number.length < 4: ###
      else if number.length < 7: (###) ###
      removes country codes
      */
      if (!number) {
        return '';
      }

      number = String(number);
      number = number.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
      
      // Will return formattedNumber. 
      // If phonenumber isn't longer than an area code, just show number
      var formattedNumber = number;

      // if the first character is '1', strip it out 
      var c = (number[0] == '1') ? '1 ' : '';
      number = number[0] == '1' ? number.slice(1) : number;

      // (###) ###-#### as (areaCode) prefix-endxextension
      var areaCode = number.substring(0, 3);
      var prefix = number.substring(3, 6);
      var end = number.substring(6, 10);
      var extension = number.substring(10, 15);

      if (prefix) {
        //formattedNumber = (c + "(" + area + ") " + front);
        formattedNumber = ("(" + areaCode + ") " + prefix);
      }
      if (end) {
        formattedNumber += ("-" + end);
      }
      if (allowExtension && extension) {
        formattedNumber += ("x" + extension);
      }
      return formattedNumber;
    };
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="exampleController">
  <p>Phone Number Value: {{ user.profile.HomePhone || 'null' }}</p>
  <p>Formatted Phone Number: {{ user.profile.HomePhone | phoneNumber }}</p>
        <phone-number id="homePhone"
                      class="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Home Phone" 
                      model="user.profile.HomePhone"
                      ng-required="!(user.profile.HomePhone.length || user.profile.BusinessPhone.length || user.profile.MobilePhone.length)" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified the code to output phone in this format Value: **+38 (095) 411-22-23**
Here you can check it [enter link description here](http://codepen.io/desructorvad/pen/LGjMMO)

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currencyVal;
});

myApp.directive('phoneInput', function($filter, $browser) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var listener = function() {
                var value = $element.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                $element.val($filter('tel')(value, false));
            };

            // This runs when we update the text field
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                return viewValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0,12);
            });

            // This runs when the model gets updated on the scope directly and keeps our view in sync
            ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
                $element.val($filter('tel')(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, false));
            };

            $element.bind('change', listener);
            $element.bind('keydown', function(event) {
                var key = event.keyCode;
                // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
                // This lets us support copy and paste too
                if (key == 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)){
                    return;
                }
                $browser.defer(listener); // Have to do this or changes don't get picked up properly
            });

            $element.bind('paste cut', function() {
                $browser.defer(listener);
            });
        }

    };
});
myApp.filter('tel', function () {
    return function (tel) {
        console.log(tel);
        if (!tel) { return ''; }

        var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

        if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
            return tel;
        }

        var country, city, num1, num2, num3;

        switch (value.length) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                city = value;
                break;

            default:
                country = value.slice(0, 2);
                city = value.slice(2, 5);
                num1 = value.slice(5,8);
                num2 = value.slice(8,10);
                num3 = value.slice(10,12);            
        }

        if(country && city && num1 && num2 && num3){
            return ("+" + country+" (" + city + ") " + num1 +"-" + num2 + "-" + num3).trim();
        }
        else if(country && city && num1 && num2) {
            return ("+" + country+" (" + city + ") " + num1 +"-" + num2).trim();
        }else if(country && city && num1) {
            return ("+" + country+" (" + city + ") " + num1).trim();
        }else if(country && city) {
            return ("+" + country+" (" + city ).trim();
        }else if(country ) {
            return ("+" + country).trim();
        }

    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-pattern which is more easy and more light.
http://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/learn-regular-expressions-in-20-minutes/.
Here u can know about it,,,just some meaningful words,,,not needs any directive or filter,,,,

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with a custom Angular filter as well, but mine takes advantage of regex capturing groups and so the code is really short. I pair it with a separate `stripNonNumeric` filter to sanitize the input:

```
app.filter('stripNonNumeric', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return (input == null) ? null : input.toString().replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
});
```

The `phoneFormat` filter properly formats a phone number with or without the area code. (I did not need international number support.)

```
app.filter('phoneFormat', function() {
    //this establishes 3 capture groups: the first has 3 digits, the second has 3 digits, the third has 4 digits. Strings which are not 7 or 10 digits numeric will fail.
    var phoneFormat = /^(\d{3})?(\d{3})(\d{4})$/;

    return function(input) {
        var parsed = phoneFormat.exec(input);

        //if input isn't either 7 or 10 characters numeric, just return input
        return (!parsed) ? input : ((parsed[1]) ? '(' + parsed[1] + ') ' : '') + parsed[2] + '-' + parsed[3];
    }
});
```

Use them simply:

```
<p>{{customer.phone | stripNonNumeric | phoneFormat}}</p>
```

The regex for the `stripNonNumeric` filter came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862219/3123195).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create custom form controls (as directives) for the phone number and the credit card.  See section "Implementing custom form control (using ngModel)" on the [forms](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) page.

As Narretz already mentioned, Angular-ui's [Mask directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/tree/master/modules/directives/mask) should help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Simple filter something like this (use numeric class on input end filter charchter in []):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Only allow number input
$('.numeric').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9+-\.\,\;\:\s()]/g, ''); // this is filter for telefon number !!!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I created ssn directive which checks for the the pattern and I have used RobinHerbots  `jquery.inputmask`

```
angular.module('SocialSecurityNumberDirective', [])
       .directive('socialSecurityNumber', socialSecurityNumber);

function socialSecurityNumber() {
    var jquery = require('jquery');
    var inputmask = require("jquery.inputmask");
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1000,
        link: function(scope,element, attr, ctrl) {

            var jquery_element = jquery(element);
            jquery_element.inputmask({mask:"***-**-****",autoUnmask:true});
            jquery_element.on('keyup paste focus blur', function() {
                var val = element.val();    
                ctrl.$setViewValue(val);
                ctrl.$render();

             });

            var pattern = /^\d{9}$/;

            var newValue = null;

            ctrl.$validators.ssnDigits = function(value) {
                 newValue = element.val();
                return newValue === '' ? true : pattern.test(newValue);    
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find [Plunker for Formatting Credit Card Numbers](http://plnkr.co/edit/f9oYZkqClSqe3plzDH44?p=preview) using angularjs directive. Format Card Numbers in xxxxxxxxxxxx3456 Fromat.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

   .directive('maskInput', function() {
    return {
            require: "ngModel",
            restrict: "AE",
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
             },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                var orig = scope.ngModel;
                var edited = orig;
                scope.ngModel = edited.slice(4).replace(/\d/g, 'x') + edited.slice(-4);

                elem.bind("blur", function() {
                    var temp;
                    orig  = elem.val();
                    temp = elem.val();
                    elem.val(temp.slice(4).replace(/\d/g, 'x') + temp.slice(-4));
                });

                elem.bind("focus", function() {
                    elem.val(orig);
               });  
            }
       };
   })
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.creditCardNumber = "1234567890123456";
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Inject 'xeditable' module in your angular app(freely available):

`var App = angular.module('App', ['xeditable']);`

And then use its built in feature in your HTML code as follows:

`<div>{{ value|number:2 }}</div>`