# AngularJS and AngularUI: mask or format a phone number when binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-bind-html

I am using AngularUI to format or "masking" a phone number input, and it works fine with a ng-model:

```
<input ng-model="emer.phone" ui-mask="{{'(999) 999-9999'}}" type="text"/>
```

Question:
But now how can I apply the same mask in the same way using ng-bind, I have something like this:

```
<td>{{emer.phone}}</td>
```

My problem:
The ng-model and ng-bind are in two different files in different locations, therefor the use of "$viewValue" is not an option for me

Any idea?

some documentation about AngularUI mask: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You should use `ui-mask="(999) 999-9999"` instead of `ui-mask="{{'(999) 999-9999'}}"`.

The latter tries to bind to a model with `'(999) 999-9999'` on it.

Answer (score 7):

SO far I couldn't find a simple solution using AngularUI mask, so I had to create a filter. I follow this: [Format telephone and credit card numbers in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700145/how-to-format-a-telephone-number-in-angularjs)

And here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jorgecas99/S7aSj/

```
angular.module('ng').filter('tel', function () {
    return function (tel) {
        if (!tel) { return ''; }

        var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');
        ...
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making your own masking or perhaps building your own directive you can make use of existing solutions.

Take tel.js for example. It is an input[tel] directive that formats and validates international phone numbers for you.

You can install it from bower like this:

```
bower install teljs --save
```

Then:

1. Link the two script files found in the 'src' folder: tel.js and metadatalite.js.

   ```
   <script src="bower_components/teljs/src/tel.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/teljs/src/metadatalite.js"></script>
   ```
2. Load the tel.js module.

   ```
   angular.module('<your module>', ['teljs']);
   ```

You can try out tel.js here:

http://michaelkrog.github.io/tel.js/

Remark: I am the developer of tel.js.

Answer (score 2):

I can see in the `ui-mask` [demo](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/mask/demo/index.html), they cheat a bit and use the `$viewValue` from `ngModelController`.

So, you could try the same thing.

First, you must add a name to your input field and be wrapped in a form (with a name):

```
<form name="demo">
    <input name="emerPhone" ng-model="emer.phone" ui-mask="{{'(999) 999-9999'}}" type="text"/>
    <td>{{demo.emerPhone.$viewValue}}</td>
</form>
```

As you can see from the above example, the display code becomes:

```
<td>{{demo.emerPhone.$viewValue}}</td>
```

It would have been better if they would have provided a filter as well, though.

Also, I can see that in [the demo for ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/mask/demo/index.html), they show and hide based on the `length` of the `$viewValue`:

```
<div ng-show="demo.masked.$viewValue.length">NgModelController.$viewValue: <code>{{ demo.masked.$viewValue
              }}</code></div>
            <div ng-hide="demo.masked.$viewValue.length">NgModelController.$viewValue: <code>undefined</code></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Davin, thanks for your comment :)... unfortunately I can use it in that way because my ng-model and ng-bind are in two different views and different files, therefor the $viewValue id not available :(. Id there any other option for me?

Comment: With ui-mask there doesn't seem to be any other option.  You may have to write your own filter.

Comment: typo: "unfortunately I can't* use it"

Answer (score 0):

Find [Plunker for Formatting Credit Card Numbers](http://plnkr.co/edit/f9oYZkqClSqe3plzDH44?p=preview) using angularjs directive. Format Card Numbers in xxxxxxxxxxxx3456 Fromat.

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])

   .directive('maskInput', function() {
    return {
            require: "ngModel",
            restrict: "AE",
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
             },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                var orig = scope.ngModel;
                var edited = orig;
                scope.ngModel = edited.slice(4).replace(/\d/g, 'x') + edited.slice(-4);

                elem.bind("blur", function() {
                    var temp;
                    orig  = elem.val();
                    temp = elem.val();
                    elem.val(temp.slice(4).replace(/\d/g, 'x') + temp.slice(-4));
                });

                elem.bind("focus", function() {
                    elem.val(orig);
               });  
            }
       };
   })
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.creditCardNumber = "1234567890123456";
  }]);
```