# angulars js client side validation on phone number unable to combine regex formats

Tags: angularjs, validation

The following formats are allowed for the phone number

1. xxx-xxx-xxxx  [x represents a digit]
2. xxx.xxx.xxxx
3. xxxxxxxxxx   [digit ten times]

I have the working sample for the formats but I am unable to combine them in a single regex. How to combine them into a single regex?

1. `"/^[1-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}|^\d{10}$/"`
2. `"/^[1-9]\d{2}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{4}|^\d{10}$/"`
3. `"/^\d{10}$/"`

My regex code in angular:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':userprofileForm.phone.$touched && userprofileForm.phone.$invalid && userprofileForm.extension.$touched && userprofileForm.extension.$invalid}">
   <label for="profile-phone" class="control-label">{{'PHONE'|translate }}</label>
    <div>
       <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userprofile.phoneNumber" ng-pattern="/^\d{10}$/" required="required" />
       <div ng-show="userprofileForm.phone.$touched && userprofileForm.phone.$invalid">    
          <span ng-message="required">Please enter phone number</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them like so:

```
ng-pattern="/^([1-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4})|([1-9]\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{4})|(\d{10})$/"
```

Just put every pattern in its own group with `()` and *or* them together with `|`.

Or more compact using a *back reference* (assuming your third case should also not start with a `0`):

```
 ng-pattern="/^[1-9]\d{2}([.-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}$/"
```

RegEx breakdown:

```
^       // start of line
[1-9]   // match '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' or '9'
\d{2)   // match 2 digits
(       // begin capturing group 1
[.-]    // match '.' or '-' 
?       // make the preceeding [.-] optional, so capturing group 1 matches '.', '-' or nothing. 
)       // end capturing group 1
\d{3)   // match 3 digits
\1      // back reference: match what was matched by capturing group 1
\d{4)   // match 4 digits 
$       // match end of line
```

Note that due to the use of the back reference a mix like xxx.xxx-xxxx is correctly rejected.

Comment: `[1-9]` is not `\d`. +1 for using a back reference.

Comment: catch ="/^[1-9]\d{2}([.-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}$/" makes this combination valid xxx.xxx-xxxx which should not be the case.

Comment: @arvind: xxx.xxx-xxxx is invalid: /^[1-9]\d{2}([.-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}$/.test('123.456-7890') returns false. Note that the \1 is a back reference to the first capturing group, so has to mach what was matched by ([.-]?). Explanatory RegEx breakdown added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700145/format-telephone-and-credit-card-numbers-in-angularjs) with various answers including [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), regex etc.
Do check it out..

Also this handy [online regex validator](https://regex101.com/) explains your regex might help validate the syntax.

Hope this helps.