# parseInt alternative with characters in string

Tags: javascript

If I have the following:

```
(8
```

Is there a way to get the number `8` out of it without splitting it? Using `parseInt` returns `NaN`. Is there an alternative to `parseInt` that ignores non-numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: strip out non-numeric characters from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/javascript-strip-out-non-numeric-characters-from-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
parseInt(str.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a quick regex to match that number, and just prepend `+` to cast to number:

```
var num =+ '(8'.match(/\d+/)
```