# How can i trim a sub string using java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a following value i want to trim "`mi`" and other white values from the below figure.

```
value= 8.8 mi
```

the value may change every time but will come with mi.

Comment: Why you need `c#` tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
var value = "8.8 mi";
var number = parseFloat(value); // 8.8
```

Looks like what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex to remove the text from the end of the string:

```
var expr = / mi$/;
var value2 = value.replace(expr, "");
```

And like h2ooooooo commented, you can use a group to match on:

```
var expr = / (hr|mi|sec)$/;
```

Comment: And for "other white values": `/ (mi|foo|bar)$/`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Thanks. Put your remarks in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

if it's only `mi` at the end then it should work

```
value= 8.8 mi;
trimValue = value.substr(0,value.length-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value = value.substr(0, value.length - 2);
```