# How to remove all non-numeric characters from a variable

Tags: javascript

How can I remove all text characters (not numbers or float) from a javascript variable ?

```
function deduct(){
    var getamt= document.getElementById('cf').value; //eg: "Amount is 1000"
    var value1 = 100;
    var getamt2 = (value1-getamt);
    document.getElementById('rf').value=getamt2;
}
```

I want `getamt` as number. `parseInt` is giving `NaN` result.

Comment: `var getamt2 = (value1 - Number(getamt));`

Comment: @epascarello `eg: "Amount is 1000"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [strip non-numeric characters from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-string) -- See second answer `getamt.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')`

Comment: Note that you need to see one of the non-accepted answers on the dupe to handle floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression like this:

```
var getamt= document.getElementById('cf').value; //eg: Amount is 1000
var value1 = 100;
var getamt2 = value1 - getamt.replace( /\D+/g, ''); // this replaces all non-number characters in the string with nothing.
console.log(getamt2);
```

[Try this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwpu32tp/)

Comment: This only removes the non numeric values from the start of the string, not the middle or end

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the non-numbers

```js
    var str = "Amount is 1000";
    var num = +str.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,"");
    console.log(num);
```

or you can match the number

```js
    var str = "Amount is 1000";
    var match = str.match(/([0-9.])+/,"");
    var num = match ? +match[0] : 0;
    console.log(num);
```

The match could be more specific too