# Javascript Regex - Converting string to number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string where I want to remove any letters and hyphens. I have a code like below,

```
var s = '-9d 4h 3m',
    t = '1-22';

var p = /[^0-9-]+/g;
    r = s.replace(p, ''),
    a = t.replace(p, '');

console.log(r, a);
```

Here I want to remove hyphen if it is in between the numbers and omit at first. Any help or suggestions?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t25zqff/1/)**

Comment: So basically you're expecting `-943, 122` ?

Comment: @adeneo, exactly! you are right.

Comment: And you want to remove trailing hypens as well, or just "between" the numbers ?

Comment: @adeneo, trailing hypens and not just the one in between.

Comment: @aravindtrue your question is totally unclear for me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, To be simple, I want to display just numbers and remove any other characters in a string. Additionally if the string has hyphen at the beginning, no need to remove and consider it as a negative value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much more simpler one without using `|` operator.

```
string.replace(/(?!^-)\D/g, "")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sE1yR8/1)

Comment: I just thought of replacing with `\D`.. +1 :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
var p = /[^0-9-]+|(?:(?!^)-)/g;
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t25zqff/3/)

Comment: OMG, i just failed to combine both of the regexs.

Comment: @AvinashRaj happens.. :)

Comment: I think that /[^0-9-]+|((?!^)-)/g would be enough, i.e. non-captive ?: is redundant

Answer (score 0):

In your console log you put a comma between the variable but you need a plus like this.
I have also change variable a so that it removes the -

```
var s = '-9d 4h 3m';
var t = '1-22';

var p = /[^0-9-]+/g;
var r = s.replace(p, '');
var a = t.replace("-", '');

console.log(r + " " + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862219/3464552 check over here this will be a solution.

```
var s = '-9d 4h 3m',
s = s.replace(/\D/g,'');
```