# Replace all characters with Comma sign in string, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

A user can type In a separated list In an input field like this for example:

```
123, 123, 123

123!123!123

123:123:123
```

When the use Is finished, I want to replace all non-numeric characters with a comma-sign. How can I do that? When the user Is finished, I want the string to be separated with comma signs

I have tried like this:

```
var accidentFieldVal = $('#accidentId').val().split(/[ ,]+/).join(',');
accidentFieldVal = accidentFieldVal.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output, and the JS code you've written to attempt to solve this

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Expected output? The expected output should be the string with comma signs instead. Check the updated code with my attempt.

Comment: Comma signs instead of... what? `I want to replace all the characters with a comma-sign` would imply you're trying to get `,,,,,,,,,,,` but I'm assuming that's not right.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Check my question? "I want to replace all the characters with a comma sign".... Charachters, not the numbers. The !, :, and blank space

Comment: Right, now it makes sense. 'All characters' includes the numbers and symbols, hence why it wasn't clear. I edited your question to include that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strip non-numeric characters from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this

var str = "123! 22! 33"; 
var res = str.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ",");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're after a simple way to replace groups of non-digits with commas, the following will suffice:

```
function replaceWithCommas (data) {
    return data.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ",");
}
```

`[^\d]+` simply matches one or more non-numeric character.

Running:

```
console.log (replaceWithCommas("123, 123, 123"));
console.log (replaceWithCommas("123!123!123"));
console.log (replaceWithCommas("123:123:123"));
```

Outputs:

```
123,123,123
123,123,123
123,123,123
```

Comment: As another answer has pointed out, `\D` is equivalent to `[^\d]` - I'd forgotten about that one.

Comment: Thank you. But the output for me Is the followin: 123,123!123.. The last one Is not formatted.. var accidentFieldVal = $('#accidentId').val().replace(/[^\d]+/, ",");

Comment: I missed the 'global' flag on the replace  - added now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
accidentFieldVal = $('#accidentId').val();
accidentFieldVal = accidentFieldVal .replace(/^[^\d]+|[^\d]+$/g, '');
accidentFieldVal = accidentFieldVal .replace(/[^\d]+/g, ',');
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this before.. But yeah. So If I want to replace other characters, I must add this too?

Comment: Now I understood your requirement. try edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Shriya R s answer is for integers only.
If you want to use double values too, try this:

```
var target = "10:20:30:40.0";

function replaceComma(str)
{
   return str.replace(/[^\d.]+/g, ',');
}

replaceComma(target); // output: "10,20,30,40.0"
```