# How to Delete Text Mixed with Digits

Tags: jquery

I just allow someone to enter data in the form of numbers. If the data entered in the form of a mixture, the numbers and text, the text will be deleted.

However, I use jQuery which is not true. It turns out that removed precisely both the numbers and text.

The following code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="test">0123456789text</div>

<script>
if ($('#test').html()!="0123456789"){
$('#test').remove();
}
</script>
```

How do I fix it?

**Note:**
I do not have access to edit the `<input>` or `<textarea>` on the form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Comment: @Billy - Sorry, this is another story.

I was the blogger.com
If someone sends you comments, then I can not edit the part you are looking for.

Comment: well in that case it's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-string.  either way it's a dupe and this question has been asked a thousand times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to remove all is not a number is:

```
  var obj = $('#test');
  obj.text(obj.text().replace( /[^\d]/g ,''));
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is testing to see if the input matches the exact string `0123456789`, and if not removes the entire string.

To remove only the characters (and leave the numbers) you can use a regular expression.

```
var regex = /[a-z]*/ig;
var input = $('#test').html();

var cleanedInput = input.replace(regex,'');
```

Here's what this code is doing:

1. The regex matches any characters, lower or uppercase.
2. Grab the string you want to clean from your input.
3. Use `.replace()` to replace any matched characters with an empty string.
4. `cleanedInput` contains the cleaned string for later use.

Answer (score 0):

The next code to check for alphabet letters

```js
var str = $('#test').text().trim();
if (str.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
    // alphabet letters found
    $('#test').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">0123456789text</div>
```