# How to remove alphabets and special character form string

Tags: javascript, node.js

My input is string contains character and special symbol, I need only numeric value output so how can we do that using Node JS.
 `const myInput = "56,57FS+2d" //desired output is 56,57`

**For character not fixed with FS it will be change.**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know how the `FS+2d` is added to the string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip all non-numeric characters from string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-all-non-numeric-characters-from-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Shouldnt the output be this `56,572`? Why have you not included `2`

Comment: Its an JSON come from another source and I need to manipulate that value So in that JSON this type of value come.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal No I need only 56,57 not required 2d

Comment: @Gajiu I tried that but it give me 56572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex `/[a-zA-Z](.*)/g`

```js
const myInput = "56,57FS+2d";
console.log(myInput.replace(/[a-zA-Z](.*)/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will select all numbers and `,` and remove everything after `+` (here `+2d`).

```js
const myInput = "56,57FS+2d";
console.log(myInput.replace(/[^0-9,][^+]{0,}/g, ""));
```

**Output:**

```
56,57
```