# How to sort, ignoring any characters that are not numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a sort function that orders items with the class '.sortbox', finds the '.num' value and sorts using flex order.
This works fine, but some of the values have extra characters (./-) and this breaks it.

How can I search but ignore all characters that are not numbers?

My attempt here: If I have it all completely wrong then appreciate help to understand why.

https://jsfiddle.net/9cwyund6/1/

```
function sorting(){
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.sortbox')
  Array.from(items).sort(function(a, b) {
    a = ~~a.querySelector('.num').innerText
    b = ~~b.querySelector('.num').innerText
    return a - b
  }).forEach(function(n, i) {
    n.style.order = i
  })
}
```

Comment: That sort is going to have the worst performance ever. Give example HTML that is causing you issues.

Comment: You can use a [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-all-non-numeric-characters-from-string-in-javascript) in your `sort` function.

Comment: You can use isNan function to check if it is a number or not.

Comment: So -13 is higher than 3? Or even 1.3? I.e Are you sure you want to ignore these characters or do you want to parse them correctly?

Comment: This is probably my very bad attempt I agree. It is a date that is pulled in from a json file... If I ignore all characters I get the desired result.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9cwyund6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the strings a and b from all non digit characters while sorting

```
return a.replace(/\D/g,'') - b.replace(/\D/g,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
isNaN()
```

method to check if something is a number or not.